# Python: Detecting only specific string not it's variations for dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I am trying to take in all the files at a given path, and order them based on my data title names.
So my data title names are:

```
data_titles = ['CPU','Physical_Disk','Memory','Network','Network#2']
```

The files at this given path are named like `'CPU_data.txt'` and `'Memory_data.txt'`, `'Network_data.txt'`,`'Network#2_data.txt'` etc.

I am trying to create a dicitonary in the style of:

```
{'Network': 'Network_data.txt', 
 'Network#2': 'Network#2_data.txt', 
 'Physical_Disk': ['Physical_Disk_data_1.txt','Physical_Disk_data_2.txt'], 
 'CPU': 'CPU_data.txt', 
 'Memory': 'Memory_data.txt'}
```

However what I actual get is:

```
{'Network': ['Network_data.txt','Network#2_data.txt'], 
 'Network#2': ['Network#2_data.txt'], 
 'Physical_Disk': ['Physical_Disk_data_1.txt','Physical_Disk_data_2.txt'], 
 'CPU': ['CPU_data.txt'], 
 'Memory': ['Memory_data.txt']}
```

Here is my code:

```
table_csv_files={}
    for file_names in os.listdir(Data_folder):
        for name in data_titles:
            if name in file_names:
                if name in table_csv_files:
                    table_csv_files[name].update(file_names)
                else:
                    table_csv_files[name]=[file_names]

                print table_csv_files
```

How to I ensure that for the data_title `'Network'` only `'Network_data.txt'` is detected not also `'Network#2_data.txt'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `Network` can be found in both `'Network_data.txt'` *and* `'Network#2_data.txt'`. You need more than that to get a unique match.

Since these two names can be distinguished by adding a `_`, you can easily fix this by changing the test to

```
if name+'_' in file_names:
```